# Getting longitude and latitude takes a very long time

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am getting the longitude and latitude of my device, but it takes at 30 seconds to a minute to do so. Any suggestions to cut the time down?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
public String zipcode;
public double latG;
public double lonG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!enabled) 
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(intent);
    }

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {

         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
         {
                if (location != null) 
                {
                    latG = location.getLatitude();
                    lonG = location.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            latG + " " + lonG,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
            {

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
            {

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
            {

            }



    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);



    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try 
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latG, lonG, 1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Context context = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Error in getting address information.");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

    }

    for (Address address : addresses) 
    {
        if(address.getPostalCode() != null)
        {
            zipcode = address.getPostalCode();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, zipcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: check your code with network provider insted of gps provider  and see how many min it taken

Comment: Is your internet connection is speedy? what mobile device you are using? how speed the mobile processor is? is your area you are detecting the lat and long using gps is easily positionable? Test this and all and you will come to know how to reduce the time..

Comment: I would also suggest doing a code review. There are some areas for improvement within the code as well e.g. why get a reference to locationManager twice to begin with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `GPS_PROVIDER` for fetching the GPS data. `GPS_PROVIDER` fetches details directly from the satellite so it takes time for the first time you load this. Moreover `GPS_PROVIDER` takes more than 30 seconds if your are not below the open sky. `GPS_PROVIDER` may return NULL when you are inside the office or in basement.

There is an alternative way for this is to use `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. This provider will give you GPS details based on your current Network state. This will not be much accurate like `GPS_PROVIDER` but it works faster.

Answer (score 2):

hi you are using GPS PROVIDER which can take some time as it depends on several constraints like yours building position, physical position, weather as gps data is available from the satellite so use a network provider which may faster in yours case please have a look on the given code snippet at

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to use Google Play Services and its LocationClient.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

This gives you a provider that automatically picks the best available information from all the provider types and can return the location immediately in some cases using `getLastLocation()`

Answer (score 1):

try to run it in device rather than running it in the emulator.

Comment: Will you get the gps result in emulator? Read the users question and answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 try {
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}


if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        }
        if (network_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
```

It will give the response what ever the service is available.Even you can place your priority

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to fetch faster,

```
String provider;
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

            if (location != null) 
                         {
                onLocationChanged(location);
                              //your remaining code
                         }
```